# page footer in last page

Tags: html, css, printing

I created a html page that provides to print his's content(window.print). I would like to add page footer for print version with the following CSS.

```
display: table-footer-group;
```

But I want to have a page footer in last page. The above CSS produces the page footer every page. How can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Did you  find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
@page:last {
    /* footer css here */
}
```

[Additional reading.](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/)

Comment: :last doesn't exist